# Deleting a question about a challenge from a running contest

Tags: support

Would it be possible to delete [How to print the file in linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019568/how-to-print-the-file-in-linux-terminal)? This question is about a challenge from an ongoing contest and the answer provides some hints which help solve the challenge. Alternatively, even deleting the answer is fine.

Answer (score 27):

Generally, it's not the policy of moderators to close or delete questions involving ongoing contests or schoolwork. If a question is a viable programming question, it's not on us to enforce the terms and conditions of an outside site or contest.

This question just wasn't a good question to begin with, so it was closed and removed because of that. Don't take this as evidence that other questions involving contests should be removed, though.

Answer (score 0):

The question is closed already, and will probably be deleted soon enough... Especially now it's gotten some extra attention.

The answer shouldn't be deleted on it's own, though, as the *answer* is of sufficient quality.

Edit: And as "predicted", the question is deleted now.

Comment: Maybe "will be deleted" was better... "Should" implies that that's how it should be done...